# How to restore the default checkout template?

Tags: checkout, layout, theme, template

I never use Magento but, a friend uses it and a dev. broke their checkout page, how I can restore the TEMPLATE of the checkout to default? I don't see a backup of any of the files, and I no have clue where I need to start searching in the directory tree.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how the template is being overridden, usually either a new template is specified in layout XML or a template is placed in the same path as the original but in the custom theme.

If you delete the template in your custom theme and re-deploy the core template should be used again.

We need a bit more info to help in more depth though:

- What version of Magento are you using?
- What is the template you want to revert

### Update

To revert the checkout back to core this should be simple if the changes were done in a theme, if so delete `app/design/frontend/{VENDOR}/{THEME}/Magento_Checkout`.

If the changes were done there your checkout should now be using the core templates/JS/styling.

Another option is the changes could have been made in a module, this is a bit tricker to find. You could look for files named `onepage.phtml` or `checkout-steps.js` and see if any modules are overriding them, or alternatively search for `checkout` but that will return maaaany results.

Comment: Is magento 2.3
Only the index.php/checkout page. All other are okay, now that template display wrongs inputs and color/UI are really bad, i wanna rollback to the original M2 checkout.

I have a fresh instalation in other server but idk what file i need to reemplace or what CLI command i need to execute.

Comment: I've added a bit more info to my answer based on it being the checkout.